# Print dataframe to excel with name

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have a dataframe `df` which has values as:

```
Year    c1      c2      c3      c4
2013    9.51    7.74    10.41   
2014    21.53   8.44    25.92   14.24
2015    13.85   8.09    16.10   1.92
2016    10.51   8.28    11.49   0.82
2017    7.92    10.70   7.33    
2018    28.53   20.13   31.06   4.38
Average 15.31   10.56   17.05   5.34
```

df.columns

```
Index(['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'], dtype='object', name='PeakPeriod')
```

`df.to_excel` prints only the table not the column name `PeakPeriod`

Is there a way to print this to excel so that it looks as the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("file_name.xlsx")
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1',startrow = 1)  
workbook1 = writer.book
worksheets = writer.sheets
worksheet1 = worksheets['Sheet1']
worksheet1.write(0, 0, df.columns.name)  
writer.save()
writer.close()
```